How to use the godot-llama-cpp plugin
Godot newbye here. I made a simple chatbot demo (repo here) in Godot, which takes as input the text typed by a user and outputs the replies generated by a large language model running locally using Ollama.
When I run the demo, it takes about 30 seconds to get replies on a machine with 12 GB VRAM. If I chat with Ollama directly the response time is less than a second, and if I use the API with curl (curl http://localhost:11434/api/generate -d '{ "model": "qwen2:1.5b", "prompt": "What is water made of?", "stream": false}') the response time is a few seconds.
It looks like the long response time is how I interfaced Godot with Ollama. To speed up the response time, I am trying to use the godot-llama-cpp plugin. I followed the installation steps until 6 (Add the LlamaContext node to your scene). Specifically, what are the steps for adding the node to the scene? Any help is very appreciated.
